# Swagger with ServiceStack does not send elements to server on POST

Tags: servicestack, swagger

I have a simple session object which looks like this

```
[Route("/Session", Summary = "Creates a security session", Notes = "Some session related notes here")]
public class Session : IReturn<SessionResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "DomainName", Description = "The Security Domain", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "UserName", Description = "The User Name", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [ApiMember(Name = "Password", Description = "The password", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to swagger UI I can see the elements

However when I enter the element and press Try it now, I see that the request contents are not sent to the server.

Have I configured my poco correctly with parameterType="path" or should I be doing something else here? Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Has there been any update on getting this to work without seeing your path parameters in the body parameter definition?

```
[Route("/users/{UserId}/races", "POST", Summary = "Associates a race with a user")]
public class AddUserRace : IReturnVoid
{
    [ApiMember(Description = "User Id to associate a race with to", ParameterType = "path", Verb="POST", DataType = "int", IsRequired = true)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Description("Race Id of race to associate with user")]
    public int RaceId { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Swagger UI Result]

Ideally, since UserId is a path param, I'd want it hidden from the DTO body.

Answer (score 1):

**Have I configured my poco correctly with parameterType="path" or should I be doing something else here?**

I don't think so. Configuring each of your Session properties to `ParameterType='path'` suggests that you want each property to be a variable/field with the path/url (documentation [here](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Parameters)). So you would want your ServiceStack route to look something like this if you want to use 'path'.

```
[Route("/Session/{DomainName}/{UserName}/{Password}"]
```

To me, 'query' or 'body' would be a better choice. Also, [This might contain useful information as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028012/swagger-for-servicestack-post-empty-body/15037115#15037115).

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work , here is what I had to do

```
[Route("/Session", "POST", Summary = "Creates a security session", Notes = "Some session related notes here")]
public class Session : IReturn<SessionResponse>
{
    [ApiMember(Name = "SessionData", Description = "The Session Data", ParameterType = "body", DataType = "SessionData", IsRequired = true)]
    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    //[ApiMember(Name = "UserName", Description = "The User Name", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    //[ApiMember(Name = "Password", Description = "The password", ParameterType = "path", DataType = "string", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

So now I get a text area box and I need to enter the JSON for the entire session object so that the DomainName, UserName and Password get transferred, but somehow this does not seem right.

Answer (score 1):

To support sending data in the request body with the current implementation of Swagger in ServiceStack, you should have exactly one `ApiMember` with `ParameterType = "body"` (you can still have other ApiMember attributes with other other ParameterType values, if you have variables in your URL for example).

The `ApiMember` with `ParameterType = "body"` will represent the entire content of your request body. It doesn't really matter which property of your request DTO you decorate with this attribute. We do something like this to make it clear in the Swagger UI that the `textarea` generated for this `ApiMember` should be used to populate the entire request body:

```
[ApiMember(Name = "RequestBody", ParameterType = "body", IsRequired = true,
    Description = SomeLongStringConstantThatDescribesTheEntireDTO]
```

In the Swagger UI, this will display a `textarea`, you will need to enter the entire DTO as JSON in this text area. In your case, it would be something like:

```
{"DomainName": "...", "UserName": "...", "Password": "..."}
```

Comment: Note that this answer, while relevant at the time was posted, now only applies to earlier versions of ServiceStack v3. The latest versions of ServiceStack, both v3 and v4, have much improved Swagger integration, including automatically request the request body without needing explicit ApiMember attributes.